# Matplotlib not recognizing mathtext

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've looked through previous problems with mathtext and none of them are quite what I'm seeing. All I'm trying to do is include a Greek letter in my title:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

rho=np.random.rand(100)
plt.plot(rho)
plt.title('$\rho$')
```

is returning

`ParseException: Expected end of text, found '$'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)`

Any ideas? I'm running Python 3.8.13 with Matplotlib 3.5.2 on a Mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plt.title('$\\rho$')
```

or

```
plt.title(r'$\rho$)
```

The `\r` is being interpreted as a carriage return.

Comment: Thank you! Accepted, the double backslash did it!